Data Management API - Get all items of a project
Using the  method -https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search giving us the versions that are present in the project folder and recursively in the subfolders of the same. We filtered the versions that we did not want (all hidden files). The problem is that when we are getting the versions, it is not showing all the versions present in the subfolder in most cases. For example if a subfolder has 5 files it is just displaying 2 of them.
We tried removing the filter, still the result was same, it is not showing us all versions/files present in the subfolder/folder.

Now it's resolved. Pagination is another important consideration.
I was thus only receiving the versions that were listed on the first page. To obtain all the data, you must provide page[number] in the Query String Parameter. Doing this you will get all the version payload directly from the top folders of a project.

Welcome on board! Good to see you resolved the problem and took the effort to post the solution.
